# Add different id's to elements with the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

So let's say I have 3 divs like so all with the same class:

```
<div class="Hotspot"></div>
<div class="Hotspot"></div>
<div class="Hotspot"></div>
```

How would I go about assigning different ID's to each of the divs like so:

```
<div class="Hotspot" id="Hotspot-1"></div>
<div class="Hotspot" id="Hotspot-2"></div>
<div class="Hotspot" id="Hotspot-3"></div>
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: What seems to be a problem?  What have you already tried and whee exact;y are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using jquery's `attr()` function, as well as the `each()` function

```js
var i = 1;
$('.Hotspot').each(function() {
  var customID = 'Hotspot-' + String(i)
  $(this).attr('id', customID)
  i++;
  console.log(this)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Hotspot"></div>
<div class="Hotspot"></div>
<div class="Hotspot"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried something similar to this and just tried this now it seems to just add the id Hotspot-1 to all the divs

Comment: I updated it, I forgot to increment `i` in my initial example

Answer (score 0):

First off you should really edit your question to show what you have tried doing.

I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you might be new to coding.

So, on to your question:

Start by breaking your problem down to smaller, manageable sub-problems:

1. Identifying the divs
2. Looping over them
3. Assigning an ID to them.

By using this logic you can use jQuery to identify the elements by using the class selector `.` like so `$(".Hotspot")`.

To loop over them you can easily use jQuery's [**.each() function**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

And finally to add an IDto a div programmatically you can use jQuery's [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

To chain them together could look something like this:

```
var i = 1;
$(".Hotspot").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', i);
  i++;
  console.log(this);
});
```

A full example can be found on [**this fiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/LcLxef7o/)